# Getting table name from cell selection in Apple Numbers using Javascript for Automation (JXA)

Tags: javascript, numbers, javascript-automation

I'm trying to convert this [Applescript](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/examples-table-as-image.html) to Javascript for Automation.

Is there anyone who can help to write the line bellow in Javascript for Automation?

```
set thisTable to the first table whose class of selection range is range
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This will require the use of a `whose` clause for querying the element array of tables in the selected sheet—essentially, you want to find all `Table` objects whose `selectionRange` attribute is not `null` (which is analogous to asserting that its class is `range`). Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in JXA that prevents comparisons with `null`. So while it would be optimal to simply check `_not: [{ selectionRange: null }]` in the code below, I found that that approach did not work. Instead, the following appears (albeit not particularly elegantly) to do what you're looking for:

```js
Numbers = Application('Numbers')

selectedTables = Numbers.documents[0].activeSheet.tables.whose({
    _not: [{
        _match: [ObjectSpecifier().selectionRange.name, '']
    }]
})

if (selectedTables.length > 0) {
    thisTable = selectedTables[0]
} else {
    // No table is selected -- handle accordingly
}
```

This is a pretty hacky approach (it relies on the fact that `selectionRange.name` isn't even a valid key for non-selected tables), but given the buggy state of JXA, it may be the best one can do.

Further Reading:

- [Apple's documentation on `whose` clauses](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW10)
- [An OmniGraffle bug report showing some of the varieties of (and issues with) the `whose` notation](https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/bug-default-object-query-syntax-fails-in-jxa-with-og-obj-class-property/21967)
- [A list of supported `whose` filter operators](https://www.galvanist.com/posts/2020-03-28-jxa_notes/#array-filtering-with-whose)

Answer (score 0):

Another way ... selected table and selection range

```
const app = Application("Numbers"),
      doc = app.documents[0],
      sheet= doc.activeSheet,
      tbls = sheet.tables;

let seltable = tbls[tbls.selectionRange().findIndex(el => !!el)];

let selrange = seltable.selectionRange;
```